# How to move the toggle size buttom in a Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Is possible to move only the toggle button in Fancybox in an other position?

For example only the toggle size button on the top left corner of a photo.

Comment: what toggle button are you talking about? The close button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by toggle button you mean the 'x' close button then yes. Just edit the CSS and change where you want it to display.

```
#fancybox-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    right: -15px;
    ...
}
```